# What does the 'Scrollbar' setting do in a Windows 7 Theme file?

Tags: windows-7, windows, colors, themes, color-theme

In a Windows 7 `.theme` file, there is a setting entitled `Scrollbar`.  One would think it is RGB colors for the scrollbar.

But after changing the values for that setting within a `.theme` file, I see no visual difference.

The `Scrollbar` setting is located in the `[Control Panel\Colors]` section of Windows 7 `.theme` files.  What does the `Scrollbar` setting do?

---

Per request, here is an example of the `[Control Panel\Colors]` section of a Windows 7 `.theme` file.

```
[Control Panel\Colors]
Scrollbar=128 128 255
Background=0 0 0
ActiveTitle=153 180 209
InactiveTitle=0 0 170
Menu=0 0 255
Window=255 255 255
WindowFrame=100 100 100
MenuText=0 0 0
WindowText=0 0 0
TitleText=0 0 0
ActiveBorder=0 0 255
InactiveBorder=0 0 255
AppWorkspace=0 0 170
Hilight=51 153 255
HilightText=255 255 255
ButtonFace=0 0 255
ButtonShadow=0 0 170
GrayText=0 0 170
ButtonText=0 0 0
InactiveTitleText=67 78 84
ButtonHilight=128 128 255
ButtonDkShadow=105 105 105
ButtonLight=0 0 255
InfoText=0 0 0
InfoWindow=255 255 225
ButtonAlternateFace=0 0 0
HotTrackingColor=0 102 204
GradientActiveTitle=185 209 234
GradientInactiveTitle=215 228 242
MenuHilight=51 153 255
MenuBar=240 240 240
```

Answer (score 0):

When selecting Colour in the Theme section, the colour management app engages and the Scrollbar Setting is for Size (only). Color is greyed out.

So setting it (Scrollbar setting) in the theme file will just set size (not color).

Please see the screen shot.

[image]

Now, the above was done from a standard theme. If you use a Colored Theme (such as Architecture) then the Button on the Scroll bar changes colour when you click on it. It is not coloured when it has not been pressed or clicked on.

The screen shot below depicts this, but Windows 7 is a VM and the host (Snagit) is Windows 10 so the "Press" or "Click" doesn't show, but it does show up as Blue in my test.  Also below is the section of Color in the Theme file of for my standard, plain, theme.

> [Control Panel\Colors]
>
> Scrollbar=212 208 200
>
> Background=58 110 165
>
> ActiveTitle=10 36 106
>
> InactiveTitle=128 128 128
>
> Menu=212 208 200
>
> Window=255 255 255

You need a coloured theme that support this. I used Architecture.

[image]

Comment: Thanks John.  In a .theme file, `Scrollbar` is set to 3 space-separated values, each ranging from 0-255 (decimal).  That certainly looks like RGB syntax.  Furthermore, the `Scrollbar` item is in the `Colors` section, and every other value in the `Colors` section consists of 3 space-separated values, each ranging from 0-255 (decimal), and specify an RGB color.

Comment: The GUI setting you refer to should modify the `Metrics` section, but not the `Colors` section of a .theme file.

Comment: You might wish to post a screen shot in your question. I checked a standard Windows 7 machine and that was the only "Scrollbar"  I found. Can you post a screen shot of your setting and I will check.  Thanks.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, that is the only "Scrollbar" you will find in the 'Window Color and Appearance' GUI (likely due to MS shortsightedness). But you are referring to that component of the Windows GUI.  I am referring to Windows `.theme` files.  They are two different things.

Comment: So please edit your post with a screen shot of your settings. I cannot find any here and also remember Windows 7 is gone and no more fixes, so I need to see your settings to see if they can be adapted to work.

Comment: You mean post a .theme file?  I'm not using the 'Window Color and Appearance' GUI for this task.

Comment: Post a list of settings or the text file. I am working 100% blind here.

Comment: Done! Thanks for your interest.

Comment: It all works. Colour only shows up when you click on the elevator button. The whole scrollbar does not change colour.